# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'predicted_mean'

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series, arima

My code is about forecasting time series data

```
pred_uc = model_fit.forecast(steps=50)
# Get confidence intervals of forecasts
#pred_ci = pred_uc.conf_int()
```

I'm trying to visualize the forecasted data using ARIMA on Python here is my code

```
 ax = df['spei'].plot(label='observed', figsize=(20, 15))
 pred_uc.predicted_mean.plot(ax=ax, label='Forecast')
 #ax.fill_between(pred_ci.index,
           # pred_ci.iloc[:, 0],
          #  pred_ci.iloc[:, 1], color='k', alpha=.25)
 ax.set_xlabel('Date')
 ax.set_ylabel('spei')

 plt.legend()
 plt.show()
```

I'm getting this error

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'predicted_mean'
```

Help please!!

Comment: I think `model_fit` is returning two things inside a tuple. Print it and I think one of them will be what you're looking for, and you'll be able to access it's `predicted_mean` method.

Comment: [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) is a Python built in structure. What is happening is the variable `predicted_mean` is not the structure type you believe it is. Look at the part of your code that returns `predicted_mean` and ensure that the return type is what you desire.